# Removing header underline and margins from a single page

Tags: floats, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the `book` class and `fancyhdr` in TexMaker and I want to use a rotated table which will eventually take up one whole page. The largest problem is the header line as my table will overlap with it but if possible I would also like the margins to be removed/modified if the table becomes to long. I don't really want the table to run over two pages, I only want this to be applied to the single page and I would like to keep the page numbering if possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
 \rotatebox{90}{%
   \begin{varwidth}{\textheight}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
       \hline
        \bfseries  Lead Author & \bfseries pH Sensitive &  & &  \bfseries Laser & \bfseries Intensity &  \bfseries pH & \bfseries pH & \bfseries Functionalisation\\        
       \bfseries \& Reference & \bfseries Molecule &\bfseries Nanoparticle & \bfseries SPR & \bfseries Wavelength & \bfseries Ratio & \bfseries Range & \bfseries Sensitivity & \bfseries Process \\
         \hline \hline         
        C.Talley & pMBA & (50 - 80nm) & -  & 632.8nm & $\frac{1430}{1590}$ & 4.4 - 11.2 &1&Lots and lots and lots and lots of text here \\       
        \hline
       \end{tabular}
        \caption{My caption lorem ipsum}\label{tab_b}
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this be close to what you need. the proposed solution uses `\newgeometry` from `geometry` package to remove the margin, but keep the bottom margin for page number. Here `lastpage` package is added for the correct page numbering.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=0cm, right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=1.5cm}
\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
 \rotatebox{90}{%
   \begin{varwidth}{\textheight}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
       \hline
        \bfseries  Lead Author & \bfseries pH Sensitive &  & &  \bfseries Laser & \bfseries Intensity &  \bfseries pH & \bfseries pH & \bfseries Functionalisation\\        
       \bfseries \& Reference & \bfseries Molecule &\bfseries Nanoparticle & \bfseries SPR & \bfseries Wavelength & \bfseries Ratio & \bfseries Range & \bfseries Sensitivity & \bfseries Process \\
         \hline \hline         
        C.Talley & pMBA & (50 - 80nm) & -  & 632.8nm & $\frac{1430}{1590}$ & 4.4 - 11.2 &1&Lots and lots and lots and lots of text here \\       
        \hline
       \end{tabular}
    \end{varwidth}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, that seems to work perfectly thank you

Comment: Glad I can help.